# Directory.createDirectory creates files instead of directory in iOS

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, directory

I have to save some data locally on iOS device for an Unity Game. Unity provide

```
    Application.persistentDataPath
```

to get public directory to save data. And printing it on console shows that this path returned for iOS is correct i.e. /Users/userName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/********-****-****-****-************/data/Containers/Data/Application/********-****-****-****-************/Documents/

So one function returns the path and other check if directory exists, if not it should create an directory but it creates FILE without any extension. Here is my code

```
    void savePose(Pose pose){

        if (!Directory.Exists(PoseManager.poseDirectoryPath())){
            Directory.CreateDirectory(PoseManager.poseDirectoryPath());
            //Above line creates a file  
            //by the name of "SavedPoses" without any extension
        }
        // rest of the code goes here
    }

    static string poseDirectoryPath() {
        return Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath,"SavedPoses");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible sloutions:

**1**.`Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath,"SavedPoses");` adds back slash before `savedPoses` while others are forward slashes. Maybe this causes a problem on iOS. Try raw string concatenating without the `Path.Combine` function.

```
static string poseDirectoryPath() {
    return Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "SavedPoses";
}
```

**2**.If the `Directory` class does not work properly, Use the `DirectoryInfo` class.

```
private void savePose(Pose pose)
{
    DirectoryInfo posePath = new DirectoryInfo(PoseManager.poseDirectoryPath());

    if (!posePath.Exists)
    {
        posePath.Create();
        Debug.Log("Directory created!");
    }
}

static string poseDirectoryPath()
{
    return Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "SavedPoses");
}
```

**EDIT**:

Likely a permission problem on iOS.

You can should create the folder in the [`StreamingAssets`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) directory. You have permission to read and write to this directory.

The general way to access this is with `Application.streamingAssetsPath/`.

On iOS, it can also be accessed with `Application.dataPath + "/Raw"`.

On Android, it can also be accessed with `"jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/";` and for Windows and Mac with `Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets";`. Just use the one that works for you.

For your question, `Application.dataPath + "/Raw"+"/SavedPoses";` should do it.

Comment: **1.** This was my original code, changed it after checking an other question. And as I have mentioned generated path is correct with forward slash in both case ( raw string and Path.Combine) **2** This also generates same problem.

Comment: What Unity version is this and what is the iOS version you are testing this on?

Comment: Unity = 5.4.1f1, Xcode = 7.3.1 , Simulator = iPhone 5S and iOS = 9.3. Same problem happens on device too. I am using simulator so I can view documents directory from Finder

Comment: Your version seems fine. Try `Application.dataPath + "/Raw"+"/SavedPoses";` Let me know.

Comment: **will this effect a release build?** Nope. Made the edit. Look at the Edited answer. It explains it well. That location is at the `StreamingAssets` folder and you can read and write to it. There will be no problem at-all with it. This question is about iOS and that solution will only work on iOS. You can use `Application.streamingAssetsPath` to make it work on every platform as mentioned in the edited answers.

Comment: I will start working on this in 1 hours. will surely update you. btw thanks for quick response yesterday